# How do I check if a message is a DM in Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Currently I am using the latest version of **Discord.js (v13.1.0)**.

I want to be able to detect if a certain message is a DM. I tried making a `messageCreate` event and did an if statement to check if the channel is a DM

```
client.on('messageCreate', message => {
   if (message.channel.type == 'DM') {
      console.log('Dm recieved!')
   }
})
```

This for some reason didn't work. So I have no idea what will.

**Here are my `intents`:**

`[Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS, Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES]`

Btw, the event *does* work:

```
client.on('messageCreate', message => {
   console.log('Event')
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had this issue earlier as well; I dug into the changes between discord.js v12 and v13 and figured out why.

As seen [here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#dm-channels) on the [discordjs.guide](https://discordjs.guide) webpage dedicated to the breaking changes between the updates:

> On Discord API v8 and later, DM Channels do not emit the `CHANNEL_CREATE` event, which means discord.js is unable to cache them automatically. In order for your bot to receive DMs, the `CHANNEL` partial must be enabled.

For the very important feature of handling DM messages, that notice was pretty difficult to find. It only directly mentions the `CHANNEL_CREATE` event, but basically what it means is that your bot is *unable* to receive DMs at all unless the `CHANNEL` partial is enabled in your client options.

Here is an example of how you would do that:

```
const client = new Discord.Client({ partials: ["CHANNEL"], intents: [...] });
```

You need to add that `partials` property to your `Client` constructor in order to receive DMs. After doing so, your code will work properly.

Comment: The OP says the event *is* running?

Comment: I am not sure if they meant that the event is running *for DMs* or just working in general, such as if they tested it with a guild message. They did not mention the partial being enabled in their question, so it may be the cause. I guess we'll see.

Comment: @Cannicide Ty! And yes, it was only working on guilds, not DMs. No, I didn't have any partials before. (didn't even know they were a thing -_-)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem the solution was modifying the client variable adding this

Thanks to Cannicide

```js
const client = new discord.Client({ partials: ["CHANNEL"], intents: [
    discord.Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES, 
    discord.Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING
]})
```