# Discord JS - If user sends DM to bot with specific string

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

The code below works and send a DM to the user when he/she reacts to a message.

The goal is then to add a role - or do something - if the user replies with the correct string.

```
if (reaction.emoji.name === theDoor) {
  await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(treasure);
  const reactUser = await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id);
  reactUser.send('Enter the code. Hint: *Yumi Zouma*.');
} else {
  return;
}
```

How can I make the bot handle DM from other users? Google seems to only provide how to send a DM to a user.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use then is a **Message Collector**.

[Docs](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#message-collectors)

For example,

```js
const dm = await reactUser.send("Enter code")
const collector = dm.channel.createMessageCollector({filter, max: 5, time: 30000}); //We're creating the collector, allowing for a max of 5 messages or 30 seconds runtime.

collector.on('collect', m => {
     console.log(m.content)
}

collector.on('end', (collected, reason) => {
     await dm.channel.send({content: `Collector ended for reason: ${reason} reached! I collected ${collected.size} messages.`})
}
```

Comment: Is this question not a duplicate? I'm not familiar with discord.js, but there must be already a question on how to create a Message Collector for a DM.

Comment: In addition to this answer, also check to make sure the proper partials and intents are enabled, otherwise DM messages will not be received at all. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68978438/how-do-i-check-if-a-message-is-a-dm-in-discord-js/68978631#68978631) for details. It might be worth editing that into this answer since it deals with DMs specifically, for the sake of saving future visitors and/or @flx a couple hours of head-scratching.